# how do i create a hard return or new line in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code snipet:

```
document.getElementById('PS_FORM/SUBJECT_PROPERTY/Business_Comments').value = com_textcl + "\n" ;

document.getElementById('PS_FORM/SUBJECT_PROPERTY/Business_Comments').value = com_text;
```

I want each of the values to be in their own line. Is there a way to get this done??

Thanks

Comment: What's that `Business_Comments` element?

Comment: what you mean by "values to be in their own line".. I don't get you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that element (`PS_FORM/SUBJECT_PROPERTY/Business_Comments`) is a `textarea`, then the JS should be:

```
document.getElementById('PS_FORM/SUBJECT_PROPERTY/Business_Comments').value= 
    com_textcl + "\n" + com_text;
```

If it's a `SELECT` the code would be different (update your question).

If it's a `div` or some other HTML element (rather than a FORM element) then the code would be more like:

```
document.getElementById('PS_FORM/SUBJECT_PROPERTY/Business_Comments').innerHTML= 
    com_textcl + "<br />\n" + com_text;
```

Comment: Thanks I had my "\n" in reverse order